# Cannot return a view from a different controller in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a single page application. I have an abstract class named ControllerBase, and all of my controllers inherit from it.

I have one controller named 'Application', which contains one action named 'Container'. This view contains the application view.

The way I want it to work is: if the request is AJAX, return the ActionResult from a controller. If the request is not AJAX, call the 'Application' controller and render the action 'Container', sending routing data so that the client takes care of making the AJAX calls to build the page.

Here is the controller base.

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // If the request is AJAX, let it go through
        if (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"].IsEqualTo("xmlhttprequest"))
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        // If the request is not AJAX, then the response needs to be modified.
        else
        {
            // This is the controller that contains the single-page application view.
            var applicationController = new ApplicationController();
            applicationController.ControllerContext = 
                new ControllerContext(ControllerContext.RequestContext, applicationController);        

            // Render the single page application and let it take care of the result
            filterContext.Result = applicationController
                .Container(filterContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(),
                    filterContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the application controller.

```
public class ApplicationController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Container(string controller, string action, string id)
    {
        if (controller.IsEqualTo("application")) controller = null;
        if (action.IsEqualTo("container")) action = null;
        return View(new RequestModel(controller, action, id));
    }
}
```

And here is any other controller where any requests made to it must be caught and rendered through the Application controller if it is not AJAX.

```
public class BusinessController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I route to the following route: /Business/Index, the OnActionExecuting rules work fine, but the view that comes out doesn't render the 'Container' view, it renders the 'Index' view. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the wrong view was being rendered is because the filter context was not pointing to the correct controller and action.

Here is the fixed OnActionExecuting method.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

    // If the request is AJAX, let it go through
    if (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"].IsEqualTo("xmlhttprequest"))
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    // If the request is not AJAX, then the response needs to be modified.
    else
    {
        // Get original values of controller and action data
        var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
        var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();

        // Set new values so that the view engine knows what view to render
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] = "Application";
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] = "Container";

        // This is the controller that contains the single-page application view.
        var applicationController = new ApplicationController();
        applicationController.ControllerContext = 
            new ControllerContext(ControllerContext.RequestContext, applicationController);

        // Render the single page application and let it take care of the result
        filterContext.Result = applicationController.Container(controllerName, actionName, null);
    }
}
```

Now all of my controllers will route to a single page, and that single page will take care of all requests.